# Jenkins pipeline: Why do I get an 'Invalid parameter' error when trying to zip build files?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, zip

Jenkins zip syntax wrong?

Tried the following pipeline syntax, I want to zip the build files into a .zip and copy artifact

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment{
  PACKAGE_VERSION="1.0.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
  ZIP_SOURCE_DIR="${WORKSPACE/build}"
  ZIP_OUTFILE="${WORKSPACE}/build/MyZippedBuild.${PACKAGE_VERSION}.zip"
    }
    stages {
        stage('source') {
            steps {
                echo 'Fetching'
                git 'https://github.com/battletremor/react-test'
            }
        }
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building'
            }
        }
        stage('run') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running'
                bat '''npm run build
'''
            }
        }
        
        stage('Packaging the output files'){
            steps{
                zip dir: env.ZIP_SOURCEDIR, exclude: '' , glob: '', zipFile: env.ZIP_OUTFILE, overwrite: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Got the following console output:

Started by user admin
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter "dir", did you mean "url"? @ line 30, column 21.
zip dir: env.ZIP_SOURCEDIR, exclude: '' , glob: '', zipFile: env.ZIP_OUTFILE, overwrite: true
^

WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter "exclude", did you mean "label"? @ line 30, column 45.
zip dir: env.ZIP_SOURCEDIR, exclude: '
^

WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter "glob", did you mean "label"? @ line 30, column 59.
.ZIP_SOURCEDIR, exclude: '' , glob: '',
^

WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter "zipFile", did you mean "label"? @ line 30, column 69.
EDIR, exclude: '' , glob: '', zipFile: e
^

WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter "overwrite", did you mean "url"? @ line 30, column 95.
'', zipFile: env.ZIP_OUTFILE, overwrite:
^

5 errors

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:568)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:518)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:336)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

Finished: FAILURE